# How to pass (non-empty) list of lists from Python to C++ via ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have some data in the format:

```
data = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

How can I pass it to C++ via ctypes?

I can pass individually each one of the lists like this:

```
import ctypes

temp1 = [1,1,1]
temp2 = [2,2,2]
temp3 = [3,3,3]

list1 = (ctypes.c_int * 3)(*temp1)     #NO IDEA WHAT THE * MEANS
list2 = (ctypes.c_int * 3)(*temp2)
list3 = (ctypes.c_int * 3)(*temp3)
```

But after that if I try to append all these lists into 'data'...

```
data.append(list1)
data.append(list2)
data.append(list3)

data_final = (ctypes.?????? * 3)(*data)
```

What type am I supposed to put in the ????? Thanks

Comment: The `*` means unpack, so `list1 = (ctypes.c_int * 3)(*temp1) ` is expanded to `list1 = (ctypes.c_int * 3)(1, 1, 1) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`??????` should be `ctypes.c_int * 3 * 3`

```
data_final = (ctypes.c_int * 3 * 3)(*data)
[list(a) for a in data_final]
# --> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

---

For the record, don't do

```
data = []
data.append(list1)
data.append(list2)
data.append(list3)
```

This is python, not c++, do

```
data = [list1, list2, list3]
```

Hell since you're just going to pass it to a function do

```
data_final = (ctypes.c_int * 3 * 3)(list1, list2, list3)
```

and skip the `data` step entirely

---

Just for the most pythonic way, if I had data in a `N x M` list of lists `py_list`, I'd do

```
c_array = (c_types.c_int * M * N)(*[(c_types.c_int * M)(*lst) for lst in py_list])
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. Also, when passing it to C++ as an argument, how should I do it? `py_function.argtypes = [ctypes.ARRAY]` or what is the exact type of this structure in ctypes? Thanks a lot FHTMitchell

Comment: the type is `ctypes.c_int * 3 * 3`, you can just use that. You can save it as `c_long_Array_3_Array_3` or something (that's what it's internal name is).